# Regex: how to get rid of \n in a string?

Tags: python, python-re

when I run the script:

```
import re

s = '\n Surface de la terrasse\n \n 32\n\n \n \n m²\n \n \n mètres carrés\n \n \n \n'

print(s.split())

['Surface', 'de', 'la', 'terrasse', '32', 'm²', 'mètres', 'carrés']
```

How do I get a list in the following format instead?

```
['Surface de la terrasse','32','m²','mètres carrés']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(list(filter(None, map(str.strip, s.split("\n")))))
```

Output:

```
['Surface de la terrasse', '32', 'm²', 'mètres carrés']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

First split on newlines, then strip all whitespace from beginning and end, then remove empty strings:

```
>>> print([line.strip() for line in s.split('\n') if line.strip()])
['Surface de la terrasse', '32', 'm²', 'mètres carrés']
```